# JSZip and Async.each -> not assignable to parameter of type 'JSZipObject[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async.js, jszip

I'm building an Angular 2 CLI app with Typescript where I'm parsing a zip file with text documents, using JSZip library. The code below works, but I get some errors from typescript:

> Argument of type '{ [key: string]: JSZipObject; }' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'JSZipObject[]'.
>
> Property 'find' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: JSZipObject; }'.

```
fileChangeEvent(fileInput){
  let files = fileInput.target.files[0];
  let zip = new JSZip();
  let files = [];

  zip.loadAsync(files)
    .then(zip => {
    async.each(zip.files, function(zipItem, callback) {
      zipItem
        .async('string')
        .then((content) => {

        files.push(content);
        
        callback(null);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      if( err ) {
        console.log('A file failed to process');
      } else {
        console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
        // do something with parsed files array
      }
    });
  });
}
```

There seems to be a problem passing `zip.files` to `async.each`.

As I said, it works just using ng serve, but the project can't be built unless I get rid of the errors.

Anyone knows why I get them?

Can I do the same thing with promises/generators/whatever and skip async.each?

Comment: why are you overwriting the files variable and set it to an array?

Comment: It's just as an example. Doesn't matter since that's not the problem.

Comment: having a complete and correct reproducible example helps a lot in solving your problem. :)

Comment: by the looks of it the types of your variables don't quite match, I'd check those. :)